# Can I add all user data in one object in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to add all data in one object in the collection,
for example :

```
 {
  id:134....,
  fullname : "jack...",
  email : "amsdk@gm....",
  messages :[
   all messages here
   Perhaps up to fifty thousand items
 ],
  orders : [
   all orders here
 ],.........
 }
```

Does this cause any overload on the server?

Comment: It probably won’t “overload” the server, but it may bump you against the size limit of one document eventually.

Comment: I will not load all data in the request , But I will carry a port of the data in each request , But on the whole, does this planning cause overload or any pressure on the server or delay in fetching data?

Comment: By meaning "keeping a lot of data in an array, and contstantly adding to it", then this would be a very bad idea. As stated earlier, the main concern with **"single document"** is the hard BSON size limit of 16MB. Whist that really is *"quite a lot"* and really a whole lot more than what causes common *"panic"* to not embedding arrays in documents, the reality simply is that if you can fit your **"whole database"** into 16MB, then you basically don't need MongoDB or any "database" system at all. Raw data files suit "small data" far better.

Comment: And to clarify, YES. Performance would get gradually worse with more items added to an array. Mostly it depends on what you would be doing. Constantly using `$push` only, may not be so bad. Positional updates for matched elements, would likely get worse along with other "array searching" methods. Use "documents" for things that are naturally "documents".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongo docs have helpful guidance for [selecting a data model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design). The nested model you describe above is known as the [Embedded Data Model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-embedding):

> In general, embedding provides better performance for read operations,
>   as well as the ability to request and retrieve related data in a
>   single database operation. Embedded data models make it possible to
>   update related data in a single atomic write operation.

Embedding documents simplifies getting data **out** of the database. The flip-side is that it can be challenging to add and update documents with a complex document hierarchy.

Mongo calls a traditional PK/FK structure the [Normalized Data Model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models)

> In general, use normalized data models:
>
> - when embedding would result in duplication of data but would not provide sufficient read performance advantages to outweigh the implications of the duplication.
> - to represent more complex many-to-many relationships.
> - to model large hierarchical data sets.

The Aggregation Pipeline can be scary, which may make an Embedded Data Model tempting. If you feel that way, check out this [free course on the MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about). A Normalized Data Model may be more appealing if you can confidently retrieve related data across collections.

Test read/write queries with a small data set for each model. You'll gain clarity about the benefits and challenges of each approach. For my current project, I found a Normalized Data Model simplified the many write operations required. Ultimately, separating concerns like *orders* and *users* into distinct collections proved simpler, especially once I understood how to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to merge data from related collections.